# how can I sort properly with preg_match?

Tags: php, sorting, preg-match

I'm trying to modify a line in PHP file that deals with data that comes from XML(about 600 stations). The php make this data usable by a streamer media player.
The original line is this

```
if (($title <> "")&& (strpos($link,"<") === false)&& preg_match("/Cha/i",$lang))
```

this gives me about 50 stations, I want to add few stations that **do not** have "Cha" in $lang but "Soprts" **and** has "China" in their $title.

So I wrote the line like this

```
if (($title <> "")&& (strpos($link,"<") === false)&& preg_match("/Cha/i",$lang)&& (preg_match("/China/i",$title)||preg_match("/Sports/i",$lang)))
```

But now I'm getting less results than before, now I'm getting only the stations that have CHA in $lang and "China" in $title. All the relevant stations that have CHA in $lang but not "China" in $title are ruled out.

As I have very limited knowledge in PHP I don't know how to make the proper sorting, someone offered me to use stripos but I don't know how to use it and his example didn't worked OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You flipped the and and or in your new code. You want:

```
if (($title <> "")&& (strpos($link,"<") === false)&& (preg_match("/Cha/i",$lang)|| (preg_match("/China/i",$title)&&preg_match("/Sports/i",$lang))))
```

Comment: Great!! tnx BriAnna that is exactly what I wanted, its working beautifully .

Answer (score 0):

You dont put bracets corretly. You can add multiple options in regex by using `|` (means `OR`) ,try this:

```
if (($title <> "") && (strpos($link,"<") === false) && preg_match("/CHA|China|Sports/i",$lang))
```