# how can I sort properly with preg_match #2?

Tags: php, preg-match

It's me again trying to understand this preg_match usage.
( [how can I sort properly with preg_match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766140/how-can-i-sort-properly-with-preg-match) )

Now I want to modify this line

```
if (($title <> "") && (strpos($link,"<") === false) && !preg_match("/wilmaa|tvsector/i",$page))
```

This line I learned ignores all the `$page` cells that contains `wilmaa|tvsector`, fine. I want to add to the screening procedure this 
`!preg_match("/18+/i",$lang)` to screen out adult content . 
I've tried all the possible combinations of && or || , I've put the ! inside and outside the () and never got it to work. All I received Is either 0 channels or the full 700 of them, tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into a problem here because `+` is a special character in regex. You need to escape it.

```
if (($title <> "") && (strpos($link,"<") === false) && !preg_match("/wilmaa|tvsector/i",$page) && !preg_match("/18\+/", $lang))
```

Also, the `i` modifier is not needed. I indicates case-insensitive matches, which wouldn't apply for your search.

Comment: Great !! Tnx AndrewR, it works. Now I can be sure the list is children safe LOL